comparing json object fail in jq
I am having a sample shell script file. In my script file I have a json data in a variable and also i have a file containing json .
I want to compare the contents of the file against the variable using jq.
The following is my script file
RESPONSE='{remoteIds:[{remoteId:[fd00:10:244:3:0:0:0:14]--(http://fd00-10-244-3--14.scctest.pod:8080),requestsReceived:1},{remoteId:[fd00:10:244:3:0:0:0:14]--(http://fd00-10-244-3--14.scctest.pod:8081),requestsReceived:1},{remoteId:[fd00:10:244:3:0:0:0:14]--(http://fd00-10-244-3--14.scctest.pod:8082),requestsReceived:1},{remoteId:[fd00:10:244:3:0:0:0:14]--(http://fd00-10-244-3--14.scctest.pod:8083),requestsReceived:1}]}'
    expected_response='/test/scripts/tests/local-policy/expectedTestResponse1.json'
    echo $RESPONSE
    echo $expected_response

    # Compare JSON objects using jq
    if jq --argjson var "$RESPONSE" -e '. == $var' "$expected_response" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      echo 0  # JSON objects are equal
    else
      echo 1  # JSON objects are unequal
      exit 1
    fi

The content of the file expectedTestResponse1.json is below
{
  "remoteIds": [
    {
      "remoteId": "[fd00:10:244:3:0:0:0:14]--(http://fd00-10-244-3--14.scctest.pod:8080)",
      "requestsReceived": 1
    },
    {
      "remoteId": "[fd00:10:244:3:0:0:0:14]--(http://fd00-10-244-3--14.scctest.pod:8081)",
      "requestsReceived": 1
    },
    {
      "remoteId": "[fd00:10:244:3:0:0:0:14]--(http://fd00-10-244-3--14.scctest.pod:8082)",
      "requestsReceived": 1
    },
    {
      "remoteId": "[fd00:10:244:3:0:0:0:14]--(http://fd00-10-244-3--14.scctest.pod:8083)",
      "requestsReceived": 1
    }
  ]
}

when i execute the script my script fails and exits . any idea what is happening. I would expect to print echo 0
thank you

You say " my script fails and exits".  How does it fail? Does it give an error message? If so, then we need to see the exact error message. Edit your question and cut&paste in the exact error.

jq --argjson var "$RESPONSE" -e '. == $var' "$expected_response" this is return 1

What you assign to the shell variable (starting with {remoteIds:[{remoteId:[fd00:10:244:3:0:0:0:14]--(http://fd00-10-244-3--14.scctest.pod:8080),‌ …) is not valid JSON. It's not even valid jq code (which is a superset of JSON).

yes you are right it is not valid json

While you're developing a script like this, don't throw out stderr. You would have quickly seen the problem
